# color print job where one has to pay for color

Tags: printer, colors

Document:  2 legal size pages, color graphic on 1/2 of one page

Print job is 2 legal pages, front/back, with one color graphic.  All other graphics are either grey scale or black & white.  Both scenarios result in my printer count increments "2" for that one color graphic page.  What's up with that?

Answer (score 1):

This is to a large extent printer dependent. Here are a couple of possibilities:

The printer may treat the entire job as a colour job if there is any colour on any page; hence your 2-page job is counted as 2 colour pages.

Some printers also use colour ink in greyscale images. That is done to increase the range of printable grey levels. In that case your 2nd page would also be treated as colour. You could check this by looking at the image with a good magnifying glass.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the print job it is probably processing each side as a separate print job. One for the front and one for the back.